# Convert a list to a string in another list

Tags: python, list, lambda

I am working on the lists but I had a problem.
There is a list as follows:

```
First_last_Name = [['hassan','abasi'],['mohammad','sajadi'],['bahman','mardomani'],['sarah','masti']]
```

Now we want to convert it as follows:

```
First_last_Name = ['hassan abasi','mohammad sajadi','bahman mardomani','sarah masti']
```

I want to try to write it in one line with lambda.

The code I am trying to apply in one line is as follows:

```
full_str = [(lambda x: str(x))(x) for x in First_last_Name]
```

output :

```
["['hassan', 'abasi']",
 "['mohammad', 'sajadi']",
 "['bahman', 'mardomani']",
 "['sarah', 'masti']"]
```

But I can't delete that internal list and turn it into a string.

Comment: FWIW, `(lambda x: str(x))(x)` is the same as just `str(x)`…

Comment: @FWIW Right, I tried to write it with lambda but I had problems with it

Comment: @SeyedMohammadSajadi Using lambda like `(lambda x: str(x))(x)` is pointless here. It just creates a wrapper around the actual `str` callable. If you continue this pattern you'll end up with `(lambda x: (lambda x: str(x))(x))(x)` and so on.

Comment: Try it with list comprehension with " ".join .

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a list comprehension and `join`

```
result = [" ".join(i) for i in First_last_Name]
```

Result:

```
['hassan abasi', 'mohammad sajadi', 'bahman mardomani', 'sarah masti']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
First_last_Name = [['hassan','abasi'],['mohammad','Sajadi'],['bahman','mardomani'],['sarah','masti']] 
  
new_list = [ " ".join(i) for i in First_last_Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer @sembei-norimaki 's solution. But as you asked about lambda:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: ' '.join(x), First_last_Name))
```

or even simpler:

```
result = list(map(' '.join, First_last_Name))
```